# Why might a JTextArea made scrollable, fail to be scrollable?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Does anyone see an issue with my code that might prevent JTextArea to become scrollable when you query data which expands it's bounds, it also seems that some words are getting cut in half, but the JScrollPane, which is supposedly supposed to fix the issue is failing at doing so.

```
package guiprojj;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.json.parsers.JSONParser;
import com.json.parsers.JsonParserFactory;


public class gui {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        final JTextArea movieinfo = new JTextArea(5,20);
        final JTextField movietext = new JTextField(16);
        final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);
        JPanel pangui = new JPanel();
        pangui.add(movietext);
        pangui.add(enter);
        scrolll.add(movieinfo);
        pangui.add(movieinfo);
        maingui.setResizable(false);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        movieinfo.setLineWrap(true);
        movieinfo.setEditable(false);
        maingui.add(pangui);
        scrolll.getPreferredSize();
        //pangui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        //pangui.add(scrolll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //movieinfo.add(scrolll);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
            {
                System.out.println(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
                 JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
                 Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));
                 String Title = (String)jsonData.get("Title");
                 String Year = (String)jsonData.get("Year");
                 String Plot = (String)jsonData.get("Plot");
                 movieinfo.setText("Title: "+Title+"\nYear: "+ Year +"\nPlot: "+Plot);
            }
            });

        }
}
```

Comment: `movieinfo.setText("Title: "+Title+"\nYear: "+ Year +"\nPlot: "+Plot);`  Consider converting the `JTextArea` to a `JTable` if the plots are short enough, otherwise use a `JTextComponent` that supports styled text and make 3 headings for the 3 sections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
final JTextArea movieinfo = new JTextArea(5,20);
final JScrollPane scrolll = new JScrollPane(movieinfo);

JPanel pangui = new JPanel();
//scrolll.add(movieinfo);
//pangui.add(movieinfo);
pangui.add(scroll);
```

A component can only have a single parent. You create the scrollpane with the text area which is good. But then you add the textarea to the panel, which is bad since the text area gets removed from the scrollpane).

You need to add the scrollpane to the panel since this is the component that contains the text area.

Comment: Okay! Cool, this worked, you wouldn't happen to have a fix for the way it will put spaces in the middle of words, rather than resizing/skipping some space to go to the next like?

Comment: This is not supported by an Swing component that I know of. The text area is not a "text editor".

Comment: Does [wrapStyleWord](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setWrapStyleWord(boolean)) fit your need?

Comment: Completely understood, but there must be some way to prevent that: http://i.minus.com/jnIzseKsa1oWp.png (Look @ the word between)

Comment: Greatly appreciate it jackrabbit, you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @EricLang, explain why you changed the "accepted" answer 18 months later? This answer explains the problem and gives the solution. The other answer does nothing. How is it better?

Comment: @camickr Was not my intent, my apologies. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a [ScrollPane.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
```

Comment: I did my research prior to posting a question.